# How to create android webview to share my location to a website?

Tags: javascript, android, geolocation, android-webview

In my simple android application, I have created a webview and put an URL to be loaded. The link needs my location to be shared. In my code i have given webview settings as follows:

```
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
```

and custom WebChromeClient

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new GeoClient());
class GeoClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        super.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(origin, callback);
        Log.d("geolocation permission", "permission >>>"+origin);
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
}
```

But the link still didn't show my location on the google map in the web. When i load that url in the android default browser it shows my current location. How can i share my location to the that link? Someone please help me out of this. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Try not calling `super.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt()`. The stock browser don't do it.

Comment: webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
             Log.d("geolocation permission", "permission >>>"+origin);
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
         }
This code works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
             Log.d("geolocation permission", "permission >>>"+origin);
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
         }
```

This code works for me :)